# Implementing the ISO/IEEE 11073-10417 standard in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ieee-11073

I currently develop an application (Android) that uses some BLE devices to capture health data. 
I have a blood glucose meter which uses the ISO/IEEE 11073-10417 norm to communicate with the smartphone via BLE.

While other BLE devices work with 16byte hexadecimal strings that are sent from smartphone to device and back (using a CRC-checksum-byte at the end) the documentation of this IEEE standard doesn't provide me with information regarding this. 
If anyone had a suggestion how to start working on that I would be very thankful as I don't know how long it will take me to find out how this stuff works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the Antidote developers here. You can check for the Antidote example for Android, or take a look in HDPy (just search for HDPy GitHub in Google) for some simple examples of IEEE 11073 parsing.

Answer (score 2):

[Antidote Libary](http://oss.signove.com/index.php/Antidote:_IEEE_11073-20601_stack) is a implemantion of standard 11073 and have one example on android.

I hope this help ;)